# json_encode() in PHP returns null values for russian

Tags: php, utf-8, character-encoding, json

strange problem occurs with json_encode(). I have some text in mysql database in russian. The text fields in DB are encoded in utf8-general-ci. when  executing`echo json_encode($this->result);` all the text that is in russian becomes "null"

Any ideas? Thank you in advance

Comment: make sure the php file encoding also is in UTF-8

Comment: Fredrik yes it was
@Maerlyn it is the formed array that needs to be encoded, the array is filled with data from the DB.
Thanks for the answers gues, the Pekka 's post helped a lot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When `json_encode()` encounters a string that contains an invalid (= non-UTF-8) character, it drops the entire string silently.

Most likely your database *connection* is not UTF-8 encoded. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3311243/utf-8-characters-displayed-as-iso-8859-1) on how to fix that.